# For each employee with dependent(s), list their last name and the name of their oldest dependent. Display the results in sequence by dependent’s name

Tags: sql

```
SELECT E.Lname,D.Dependent_name
FROM EMPLOYEE as E , DEPENDENT as D 
WHERE 
E.ssn=D.Essn
  AND 
 D.Bdate = (SELECT MIN(Bdate) FROM DEPENDENT
           WHERE Bdate IS NOT NULL)
```

This does work but it just show for 1 employee

Link to DB:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Comment: You need a **correlated** sub-query to look only through dependents of the *current* employee.

Comment: "display the results in sequence by dependent's name" - you will need an `order by` clause.

Comment: You could use this format :   select E.LName, D.Name from Employee E join (select min(Bdate) as Bdate, SSN from Dependent where BDate is not null group by SSN) Dependent  on Employee.SSN = Dependent.SSN   -- This is not complete as D.Name will not show yet. For that you can add a join by Depndent ID column if you have that..otherwise add it

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your subquery returns the minimum bdate over the whole table, resulting in only the empolyee that has the oldest dependant being filtered in. As commented by @PM77-1, you would need to correlate your subquery with the employee that you are currently processing.

```
SELECT E.Lname,D.Dependent_name
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE as E
    INNER JOIN DEPENDENT as D ON E.ssn=D.Essn
WHERE D.Bdate = (
   SELECT MIN(Bdate) 
   FROM DEPENDENT
   WHERE Essn = E.ssn
)
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

Another, probably more efficient option, is to use Postgres window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a row number to each record in the group made of all dependents of a given employee, ordered by date of birth. An outer query can then filter in the first record in each group :

```
SELECT x.lname, x.dependent_name
FROM (
    SELECT
        e.lname, 
        d.dependent_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.ssn ORDER BY d.bdate) rn
    FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN dependent d ON e.ssn = d.essn
) x WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.lname, a.dependent_name 
from 
(
     select e.lname, d.dependent_name, d.bdate, e.ssn
     from employee e, dependent d
     where e.ssn=d.essn
     order by d.dependent_name, e.lname
)a
where a.bdate= (select min(bdate) from dependent 
                where dependent.essn= a.ssn)
order by a.lname;
```

This displays the names of three employees > Smith, Wallace, Wong with their corresponding eldest dependents > Elizabeth, Abner, Joy.

Hope this solves the problem.